# Strange function

Tags: c++, function

i've got a function declaration in c++ and need to know how it's working:

```
 template<class x>
    int fun(x, x(*)(x*) );
```

The first arg is an object of type x. And how to describe the second one?

Comment: that won't work in C as templates and classes are C++ constructs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the declaration of a template function that returns an integer and takes, as parameters, an `x` and a pointer to a function that returns an `x` and takes, as a parameter, an `x*`.

The part `x(*)(x*)` is the part that means "a pointer to a function that returns an `x` and takes, as a parameter, an `x*`". The first `x` is the return type, the `(*)` indicates that it is a pointer to a function (if the parameter had a name, it would be written `x(*argname)(x*)`), and the third `x*` is just the argument.

Calling it would look like this:

```
int f(int* iptr) { return something; }

fun(4, f); // no need for the explicit template parameter because it can be deduced
```

Or more generally

```
template<typename x>
x functionname(x* xptr) { return something; }
```

It will not work in C because, as Daniel White said in a comment, C doesn't have templates.

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter type, where x is a class:

```
x(*)(x*)
```

Means "a pointer `(*)` to a function returning `x` and taking `x*`.  For example:

```
class MyClass {};
MyClass doit(MyClass* arg) { return *arg; }
MyClass instance;
int result = fun(instance, doit);
```

Comment: In terms of a declaration that would satisfy this: `x foo(x *bar)`

Answer (score 1):

It is a pointer to a function that return the object of type x, and got one parameter of a pointer to the type x.